# Select Dropdown Item on Materialize CSS using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to select item on dropdown field. The page use Materialize CSS and I'm using Selenium webdriver C#.

My last attempt was:

```
IWebElement tipoLoja = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='tipo_empresa']"));
SelectElement selectTipoLoja = new SelectElement(tipoLoja);
selectTipoLoja.SelectByValue("0");
```

But the result was:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to locate element: //select[@id='tipo_empresa']

HTML Code:

```
<br>
<div class="input-field col  s12 m4 l4 ">
<div class="select-wrapper">    
    <span class="caret">▼</span>
    <input class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-fe6e0db4-d829-b47a-86e7-0a3d5b55e74e" value="Selecione" type="text">
    <ul id="select-options-fe6e0db4-d829-b47a-86e7-0a3d5b55e74e" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
        <li class="disabled "></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
        <li class=""></li>
    </ul>
    <select data-val="true" data-val-required="Informe o Tipo da Loja." id="tipo_empresa" name="TipoLoja">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
        <option value="0">Matriz</option>
        <option value="1">Filial</option>
        <option value="2">Centro de Distribuição</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <label for="tipo_empresa">Tipo da Loja*</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please put the `html` in the question itself as links go stale, and some people like me can't access external sites. Otherwise, does this work when debugging if you wait a few seconds before executing this line? `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='tipo_empresa']"));`?

Comment: From the HTML, it looks like the `SELECT` is probably hidden and the `UL` above it is functioning as the dropdown. Try clicking the `UL` and then clicking the `LI` with the desired text. Also, why are you using XPath when all you are doing is interacting with an ID? Just use `By.Id()`.

Comment: Sorry @mrfreester I already put the code in the question. I don't tried this yet. I will try.

Comment: @JeffC, the problem is that I don't know if the code it works with ID because the line of ID is at the end of the code. But I will try works with ID.

Comment: I tried to use selecting `By.Id()` but no success.

`IWebElement tipoLoja = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tipo_empresa"));
SelectElement selectTipoLoja = new SelectElement(tipoLoja);
selectTipoLoja.SelectByText("Filial");`

The result was

>OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException :

Answer (score 0):

I have the same code and I tried to find element 
by xpath with firefug in Firefox and it worked.
Par example:

```
WebElement inputDrop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/input"));
inputDrop.click();
```

Thread.sleep(10000);

```
            WebElement type = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/span"));
            type.click();
```